# What constitutes a minor journal?

Tags: mathematics, journals, paper-submission

One reviewer of a paper I had submitted mentioned that if I were to submit to a “minor journal", there would be no need to add additional content, the current journal on the other hand would require more work. I'm quite puzzled about this statement – what qualifies as a "minor journal"? My primary focus is within the field of mathematics (graph theory). To avoid any controversy, I prefer not to disclose the name of the journal I've submitted to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some journals are considered more "prestigous" or "major" than others. There are several measures like impact factors that are used to rank journals and some are subsequently put in the first quartile, the very best journals, some in the second, third, and the least prestigious/impactful in the fourth. Other journals are not even ranked. The usefulness and correctness of such rankings might be debatable.

But in your case, the reviewer says that for your paper to be suitable for their relatively highly ranked journal, the quality needs to be improved, while other, lower ranked journals might be more open to publish a wider range and less refined kind of paper. If that is really the case might again be true or not.

You will find journal rankings - and possible fitting "minor journals" on pages like [scimago](https://www.scimagojr.com/), but if resubmitting the paper to a "lesser" journal is the way you want to go (instead of trying to improve the paper and stick with the current journal), I would suggest to first ask your supervisor(s) or colleagues with more experience in publishing their research for recommendations of such "minor journals".

Answer (score 3):

This comment should be only understood in a relative sense: that is, the referee is expressing the opinion that the results in the paper are not strong enough to be published in the journal you submitted to.  There are not "major journals" and "minor journals" but rather a continuum from the best to the worst.  (This is an oversimplification: there are many mathematics journals, but only finitely many, so surely the space of all such journals is discrete.  Also journals
are not linearly ordered; rather each person has their own partial ordering on the set of journals from which an approximation to a collective ordering emerges....)

The most important word in the last paragraph is **opinion**. The editors of the journal will most likely take this opinion seriously (the better the journal is, the more likely that one referee's opinion will prevent the journal from publishing your paper), but all they can do is reject the paper: they can't force you to agree with their opinion.  If the referee had some insightful comments about your paper that help you understand why it is not as good as you had hoped, you should probably take a fresh look at your entire thought process of where to submit the paper.  In the absence of that...it is entirely reasonable to resubmit to another journal *of similar quality to the first*.  It is only when you *repeatedly* receive the opinion that you need to submit to a lesser journal that you need to take that seriously...according to your own precise definition of "repeatedly."

Comment: Nice. Thanks. The editor did not reject my paper and give a change to revise, and I add more works in the paper.